# Quantity plus minus not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a quantity plus minus box in html that are embed from jQuery script as below.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://ayambrand-com-my-v1.cloudaccess.host/index.php?option=com_echarity&format=raw&task=api.get_product_name",
                    data: {dataArrayPost : Data},
                    success: function(data){
                        // console.log(data);
                        var a = JSON.parse(data);
                        //console.log(a);
                        var prodName = a.productName; 
                        var splitProductName = "";
                        var prodQty = a.quota; 
                        var splitProductQuota = "";
                        var prodPrice = a.price;
                        var splitProductPrice = "";
                        var discountedPrice = "";

                        var formQuantityUpdate = "<div class='amount-controller' data-module='amount-controller'><span id='qtyminus' field='quantity' class='handle'><i class='iconfont'>-</i></span><input class='input-num' type='text' id='num' name='number'><span id='qtyplus' field='quantity' class='handle qtyPlusHandle'><i class='iconfont'>+</i></span></div>";
                        var contents = '<table id="tableDonateDisplay" class="table table-hover">';
                        contents += "<tr>";
                        contents += '<th>' + 'Product' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Quantity Need' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Price Each' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'My Donation' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Amount' + '</th>';
                        jQuery.each(prodName, function(index1, value1) {
                            splitProductName = value1;
                            contents += "<tr>";
                            contents += '<td>' + splitProductName;
                            jQuery.each(prodQty, function(index, value) {
                                if (index1 == index) {
                                    splitProductQuota = value;
                                    contents += '</td><td>' + splitProductQuota;
                                    jQuery.each(prodPrice, function(index2, value2){
                                        jQuery.each(value2, function(index3, value3){
                                            if(index == index2){
                                                splitProductPrice = value3.price_value_with_tax;
                                                console.log(splitProductPrice);
                                                contents += '</td><td>' + 'RM ' + splitProductPrice.toFixed(2) + '</td>';
                                                contents += '<td>' + formQuantityUpdate + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
                                                contents += "</tr>";
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });

                        contents += "</tr></table>";

                        if (jQuery('#contentNeed').html()) {
                            //alert('The container contains something.');
                            jQuery( "#contentNeed" ).empty();
                        }else {
                            //alert('The container is empty.');
                        }

                        jQuery('#contentNeed').append(contents);
                    }
                });
```

Here is the part for jQuery for the plus minus function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // console.log('lulu');

    jQuery('#qtyplus').click(function(e) {
        // console.log('lala');

        e.preventDefault();

        fieldName = jQuery(this).attr('field');

        var container = jQuery(this).parents('.amount-controller');
        var currentVal = parseInt(container.children(".input-num").val());
        var val2 = currentVal + 1;

        if (!isNaN(val2)) {
            container.children(".input-num").val(val2);
        } else {
            container.children(".input-num").val(0);
        }
    });

    jQuery("#qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        fieldName = jQuery(this).attr('field');

        var container = jQuery(this).parents('.amount-controller');
        var currentVal = parseInt(container.children(".input-num").val());

        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
            container.children(".input-num").val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            container.children(".input-num").val(1);
        }
    }); 

    jQuery(".qtyPlusHandle").click(function(e) {
       console.log('lili');
    });
    // jQuery('span#qtyplus').on('click', function() { alert(1); });
});
```

When display in the frontpage it not working. When i'm trying running the script on jsfiddle it working wiithout any issue. There is no error message or anything on the console.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathbat87/v3mbf212/2/) part.

[image]

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: id should be unique and you should use delegate event handler to bind an event on the elements that created dynamically.

Comment: Did you get any errors in console? please post if any

Comment: No error or anything on the console @Johnsackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery(element).click()` only work for already loaded elements, but here you are loading the fields after the ajax request, so you need yo use like below

> jQuery('#qtyplus').click(function(e) {

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#qtyplus',function(e){
```

> jQuery("#qtyminus").click(function(e) {

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#qtyminus', function(e) {
```

> jQuery(".qtyPlusHandle").click(function(e) {

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.qtyPlusHandle', function(e) {
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9qkfd688/